# How to compare all array elements with particular name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I have a list of the product name in the array. I want to compare each product name with a specific product name. for eg., In array, if I found the product name "Damen Basic T-Shirt" then I want to click on that product.

**This is my code**

```
cy.get('.category-products').find('.product-name').then(($ele) => {
  const texts = Array.from($ele, el => el.innerText);
  texts.forEach(text => cy.log(text)); // It will print all the product name
  if(texts == ' Damen Basic T-Shirt '){
    cy.log('product found')
    cy.get('productname').click()
  } else {
    cy.log('product not found')
  }
})
```

Comment: And the problem is? You already have all you need in your question (_"It will print all the product name"_). Just adapt it.

Comment: if(texts == ' Damen Basic T-Shirt ')
This comparison not working

Comment: Your question wording is `"Damen..Shirt"` but your test is `" Damen..Shirt "` they're not the same.  What is the *actual* text?  Does it have a single leading+trailing space?  You might like to use `texts.trim() == 'Damen Basic T-Shirt'`.

Comment: This is the text.
<h2 class="product-name"> <a href="https://www.shirtee.com/de/frauen-basic-t-shirt/"> Damen Basic T-Shirt </a></h2>

Comment: Well, *text* `"<h2...</h2>"` *clearly* doesn't match `"Damen ..Shirt"`.   Not sure why your text is `<h2>...` when you use innerText.

Comment: @freedomn-m `texts` is an array of strings. This would only work with one string only.

Comment: @Andreas another reason why checking what the actual text is that's being compared - it's clearly not the value it's being compared with if it's an array (and it is)

Comment: You need the elements itself and not strings in them. You need a form of loop (e.g. `.forEach()`) to iterate over the elements. You have to find a way to get the product name (and only that). You then have to compare that product name _in the loop_ and then "click" that element if the name matches.

Comment: You should start with the [basics of working with JS arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) first so that you understand the solution.

Comment: `if(texts == ' Damen Basic T-Shirt '){` here you are comparing a array of string with an array. You can use `if(texts.includes(' Damen Basic T-Shirt '){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `then()` you can directly use `each()` to iterate through the elements and when you find your desired text, click on it.

```
cy.get('.category-products').find('.product-name').each(($ele) => {
    if ($ele.text().trim() == 'Damen Basic T-Shirt') {
        cy.log('product found')
        cy.wrap($ele).click()
    } else {
        cy.log('product not found')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a filter, don't iterate each one - the 'product not found' will come up for all the other items

```
cy.get('.category-products')
  .find('.product-name')
  .filter(':contains("Damen Basic T-Shirt")')
  .click()
```

or

```
cy.contains('.category-products .product-name', 'Damen Basic T-Shirt')
  .click()
```

Comment: Also working. But I want to add another action in the 'Else if' part.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to show you the proper way - looping and if/else leads to bad tests. What action do you want on all other products?

Comment: I am checking the admin panel, so I have to add the product & product name wise its description will be added.